# Execution reverted error while tokenOfOwnerByIndexERC721

Tags: ethereum, matic

Error while trying to get tokenId by index from Matic Polygon Testnet account

```
"maticProvider": "https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/<project_id>",
"parentProvider": "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<project_id>"
```

Code:

```
const network = new Network(config.network, config.version);
// TODO do somthing about the unused
const MaticNetwork = network.Matic;
const MainNetwork = network.Main;

const matic = new Matic({
  maticProvider: config.maticProvider,
  parentProvider: config.parentProvider,
  rootChain: MainNetwork.Contracts.RootChain,
  withdrawManager: MainNetwork.Contracts.WithdrawManagerProxy,
  depositManager: MainNetwork.Contracts.DepositManagerProxy,
  registry: MainNetwork.Contracts.Registry
});

matic.tokenOfOwnerByIndexERC721(
    '<accountAddress>',
    '<tokenAddress>',
     0, {
       from: '<accountAddress>',
       gas: 150000
     })
     .then(console.log)
```

This throws the error

```
(node:16166) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: execution reverted
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:303:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/tcadmin/Documents/hub/trove/trove-matic/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Contract:

```
//Contract based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

// implements the ERC721 standard
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
// keeps track of the number of tokens issued
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

    // Accessing the Ownable method ensures that only the creator of the smart contract can interact with it
    contract MyNFT is ERC721, Ownable {
        using Counters for Counters.Counter;
        Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
        using Strings for uint256;
    
        // the name and symbol for the NFT
        constructor()//(string memory _name, string memory _symbol)
            ERC721("TroveNFT", "TNFT") {}
    
        // Optional mapping for token URIs
        mapping (uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;
    
        // Base URI
        string private _baseURIextended;
        string private _creatorSign;
    
        function _setCreatorSignature(string memory signature_) internal virtual {
            _creatorSign = signature_;
        }
    
        function _creatorSignature() public view returns (string memory) {
            return _creatorSign;
        }
    
        function setBaseURI(string memory baseURI_) external onlyOwner() {
            _baseURIextended = baseURI_;
        }
    
        function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
            require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token");
            _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
        }
    
        function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
            return _baseURIextended;
        }
        
        function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
            require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
    
            string memory _tokenURI = _tokenURIs[tokenId];
            string memory base = _baseURI();
            
            // If there is no base URI, return the token URI.
            if (bytes(base).length == 0) {
                return _tokenURI;
            }
            // If both are set, concatenate the baseURI and tokenURI (via abi.encodePacked).
            if (bytes(_tokenURI).length > 0) {
                return string(abi.encodePacked(base, _tokenURI));
            }
            // If there is a baseURI but no tokenURI concatenate the tokenID to the baseURI.
            return string(abi.encodePacked(base, tokenId.toString()));
        }
    
        // Create a function to mint/create the NFT
        // receiver takes a type of address. This is the wallet address of the user that should receive the NFT minted using the smart contract
        // tokenURI takes a string that contains metadata about the NFT
        function mintNFT(address receiver,
                         string memory creator,
                         string memory tokenURI_) public onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
            _tokenIds.increment();
    
            uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
            _mint(receiver, newItemId);
            _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI_);
            _setCreatorSignature(creator);
    
            // returns the id for the newly created token
            return newItemId;
        }
    }
```

Please help !

Comment: How do you initialize the `matic` variable? I see from the error stack that it's a `web3js` `Contract` instance, but do you use the `web3` package or some wrapper? Can you share the `Contract` instance params (ABI and address), as well as the call params (`<account address>` and `<my nft address>`)? ... The error originates from a contract (not necessarily the `matic` contract, possibly a nested call), not from your code. But it throws a general error without any custom message so it's hard to troubleshoot without specific data.

Comment: @PetrHejda updated the details you asked you. Thank you for helping out

Comment: I was trying out possible solutions to the problem. But couldnnt find any. My getBalance API is working all fine and returns me 9. Which is the exact number of NFTs in my account. In the latest version of openzepplin they have deprecated setTokenURI and related APIs. Could they have also deprecated the `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` or equivalent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

The contract needs to extend `ERC721Enumerable` to have `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` implemented in it.